# How to trigger a download when an HTML button is clicked

Tags: html, download

I just posted this question and it got closed. I tried to edit it, and it wouldn't let me, so I'm posting a new question.


How can I create an HTML button that downloads .html, .js, .css, and .txt files automatically, without having to press any more buttons? I tried using the code below, but for some reason it just open the file in Google, without downloading it.

```html
<form method="get" action="file.txt">
    <button>
        Download
    </button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot force a download using a form without doing some server-side config or using a server-side script.
However, you can use a link with the download attribute.
The css is to make it look like a button

```css
.button-link {
  font: bold 11px Arial;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  color: #333333;
  padding: 2px 6px 2px 6px;
  border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  border-right: 1px solid #333333;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333333;
  border-left: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
}
```

```html
<a href="file.txt" download="file.txt" class="button-link">Download</a>
```